# Definite integral of modified bessel function of the first kind times exponential divided by square root

Tags: definite-integrals, special-functions, bessel-functions

I would like to solve the following integral. I have looked in Gradshteyn and Ryzhik but could not find a similar form. Maxima and Mathematica did not succeed in finding solutions. Is there a closed form solution for the following integral?

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}
\frac{ I_1(a \, r ) 
    \,
    \,
    e^{-r^2}}
{
    \sqrt{r^2 + b^2}
}
dr
$$

$I_1$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind.

Comment: No hope (in my opinion) for a closed form.